# Highlighting entire row if cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I require to highlight an entire row in Excel if a cell string contains the word "site" in column G. I am using conditional formatting with a formula which uses the following formula which doesn't work.

`=INDIRECT("g"&ROW())=MID("g"&ROW(),FIND("site","g"&ROW(),1),4)`

On a side note: the following works perfectly but only for exact matches where the content of the cell ONLY contains "site" as string:

`=INDIRECT("g"&ROW())="site"`

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I've edited the question. Basically the formula doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `INDIRECT` of `MID`, if you can use some lock mechanisms:

```
=FIND("site",$G1)>0
```

[image]

Here, you will see the active cell is A1, so the corresponding row Excel will compare it to will be G1, when conditional formatting looks at cell A2, it will compare it to G2.

When the conditional formatting looks at cell B2, it will compare it to G2 again because G was locked (via the $ symbol).

---

That said, your formula was not working because `FIND("site","g"&ROW(),1)` fails. The second argument gives the text `g#` (where # represents the row number) and the search fails).

Comment: Just to note to use SEARCH if you don't want case sensitivity.

Comment: Yup, definitely

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks